# Does React Native works well on MacBook M1?

Tags: react-native, apple-m1

I have to buy MacBook Air with M1. As I see, it supports react native (npm, expo etc.). Yes?

Edited 11.02: ok, solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score 6):

Yes. I use M1 MacBook Pro and develop React Native using Vscode. Everything works perfectly well.

Comment: Do you use Rosetta? If so, doesn't it cut off the computer performance? I am currently working on MacBook Pro 2020 13" and I feel that it chokes sometimes. Is it  reasonable to switch to M1? Wouldn't Rosetta affect in this case computer's performance - because in such case I think it is not smart to pay for M1 performance while it could be affected by the Rosetta. Thank you mate in advance!

Comment: @spatak Hi. No, I don't use Rosetta. IIRC everything in the toolchain has already switched to Apple Silicon (again, double check it as I'm not 100% sure). In either case, my previous Mac was 2019 15" i9 and the performance gain from i9 to M1 was huge. I'm sure you'll see many benefits especially in compile and launch times. While not financial advice, if you have the budget and use your Mac heavily on a daily basis for work, I strongly recommend switching to Apple Silicon M2 Mac (as of writing, latest is M2).

Answer (score 5):

It works well but it depends on what modules are you using. Some old modules are not compatible and iOS builds may fail.

**2023 UPDATE**
Everything is now compatible.

Comment: Hi, could you give an example what kind of modules you mean? 
And do you think this problem still might be a thing in 2023?

Comment: Everything is now compatible.

Comment: Hey, Matin, do you posses more information? Could you please share some links to the documentation or posts etc? Do I have to install Rossetta?

Comment: You can install rosetta but there is no need most of the time. You can start installing and setting up the environment. For Android side, just use arm-supported JDK like zulu. @spatak

Answer (score 2):

Works well just like the others mentioned. But you might encounter error where m1 chip is not supported in some cases. However, there are workarounds for them too. Such as pod install might fail, instead, you might need to run `arch -x86_64 pod install` etc.

Comment: Is Rosetta mandatory in 2023 or is React Native development fully supported on M1?